# How to use theme animation duration and curve in GetMaterialApp?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

i am using getX package, and i have replaced MaterialApp with GetMaterialApp in order to use getX screen navigation, but it seem that the properties themeAnimationDuration and themeAnimationCurve does not exist.

Thanks in advence

i have checked get material app properties in https://pub.dev/documentation/getx_baik/latest/shared_get_get_material_app/GetMaterialApp-class.html
and it seems that they exist but i got an error in my editor

Comment: @RandalSchwartz i think we are in the same page sine get package gets his last update almost one year ago

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: lightTheme(),
        darkTheme: darkTheme(),
    

        themeAnimationCurve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
        themeAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),

        // themeAnimationStyle: AnimationStyle.noAnimation, // disable it
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        home: const HomeView(),
      );
```